# PHP - Regex to replace all occurrences with multibyte support

Tags: php, unicode

`mb_ereg_replace` seems to be not supporting `g` modifier. Is there a way to do a find and replace to all occurrences with multibyte support?

Comment: What does your mb_ereg_replace command look like? I have a gut feeling that you are using preg-style regex in ereg.

Comment: no, I"m not using separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that what it does by default?

```
$original = html_entity_decode(
    '&#1041;&#1080;&#1085;&#1086;&#1082;&#1083;&#1080;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'
);

mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
$replaced = mb_ereg_replace('и', '!', $original);

echo "Original: $original", PHP_EOL;
echo "Replaced: $replaced", PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Original: Бинокли
Replaced: Б!нокл!
```

Comment: its not working for sinhala, may be it's just an issue with indic unicode range.

Comment: Sounds odd. Can you update your question with a code example of what is not  working?